# f#: Signature file causing Intellisense to complain?

Tags: f#, signature-files

Given the following code...

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract BoolA : bool
    abstract BoolB : bool
let myFn _boolVal (_i: IMyInterface) = if _boolVal then _i.BoolA else _i.BoolB
let myFnTrue = myFn true
let myFnFalse = myFn false
```

... Intellisense complains, and the compiler fails, if I create a signature file with this in it:

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract BoolA : bool
    abstract BoolB : bool
val myFnTrue : (IMyInterface -> bool)
val myFnFalse : (IMyInterface -> bool)
```

The error is `Error 10  Module 'MyModule' contains     val myFnTrue : ('_a -> bool) when '_a :> MyModule.IMyInterface     but its signature specifies     val myFnTrue : (MyModule.IMyInterface -> bool)     The types differ`.  (A similar error is reported for `myFnFalse`.)

I feel like an idiot, not being able to figure this out.  What am I doing wrong?  (Bracing for the "duh" answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your signature file, `myFnTrue` and `myFnFalse` have the signature `IMyInterface -> bool` but in your implementation `'a -> bool` with the constraint `'a :> IMyInterface` (due to [automatic generalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx)), that is, the implementation is generic and the signature is not.

The simplest solution is changing your implementation to this:

```
let myFnTrue i = myFn true i
let myFnFalse i = myFn false i
```

Comment: I see.  So although `myFn` specifies a typed argument, creating a function that takes an `IMyInterface` and returns a Boolean via `myFn true/false` results in a function with a generic first argument.

This doesn't happen with other types (e.g. I tried it with int instead of an interface, no problem there), so what is it about interfaces that causes this?

Comment: It's not possible to generalize `int`: `'a :> int` is not a valid constraint.